# What is Lagrange's Identity in terms of Covariance and Variance?

Tags: calculus, statistics

This is [Lagrange's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_identity)

What I've to put in the middle of this relation instead  $\color{red}{?}$, which led to find Lagrange's Identity in terms of variance and [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Covariance)?

$$\lvert \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)|^2+\,\color{red}{?}=\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)$$

Do I need a new mathematical operator name for it? (base on matrix trace for example)

Comment: I wonder how much the current form of this question resembles what the OP intends to ask....